# Issues with items in listview having the same text/content

Tags: c#, listview, observablecollection

I'm binding a listview to an ObservableCollection of strings.

Xaml:

```
<ListView Margin="4" Name="LvRiserList" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding GetAllRiserTags, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> GetAllRiserTags
{
    get
    {
        var riserTags = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        foreach (var riser in RiserCollection)
        {
            riserTags.Add(riser.Tag);
        }
        return riserTags;
    }
}
```

The list is populated one by one when a button is clicked, and each tag is given a default value of "empty".

The list will populate the list as expected, but the problem occurs when I try to select one of the items; only the first one gets selected. If I give the tags different (unique) default name, they get selected as expected.

Any idea to why it behaves this way?

Comment: Include the code that you're using to "select" the items.

Comment: Are you click-selecting? If so, verify that you are clicking on the TextBlock itself and not an empty part of the ListViewItem; because using a TextBlock as a ListView ItemTemplate will cause the item to span only to it's content-length.

Comment: I try to select them with my mouse. If I click the third item, the first item will be marked with blue.

Comment: It is the same result if I use Label or TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ListView.ItemTemplate and give it a try.

```
<ListView Margin="4" Name="LvRiserList" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding GetAllRiserTags, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ListView>
```

Comment: It gave the same result. The itemtemplate was unnecessary, but removing it didn't solve my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class containing an id and a value property. Overwrite the GetHash and Equals functions.
In your Viewmodel count the id or give it some unique value.

Bind to the value property.

With strings of the same value you will always encounter this problems, if you wont use a custom class :)